# Filtering tab completion in input task implementation

Tags: sbt, tab-completion

I'm currently implementing a SBT plugin for [Gatling](https://github.com/excilys/gatling).
One of its features will be to open the last generated report in a new browser tab from SBT.
As each run can have a different "simulation ID" (basically a simple string), I'd like to offer tab completion on simulation ids.

An example :

Running the Gatling SBT plugin will produce several folders (named from simulationId + date of report generaation) in `target/gatling`, for example `mysim-20140204234534`, `myothersim-20140203124534` and `yetanothersim-20140204234534`.

Let's call the task `lastReport`.
If someone start typing `lastReport my`, I'd like to filter out tab-completion to only suggest `mysim` and `myothersim`.

Getting the simulation ID is a breeze, but how can help the parser and filter out suggestions so that it only suggest an existing simulation ID ?

To sum up, I'd like to do what `testOnly` do, in a way : I only want to suggest things that make sense in my context.

Thanks in advance for your answers,

Pierre

Edit : As I got a bit stuck after my latest tries, here is the code of my inputTask, in it's current state :

```scala
package io.gatling.sbt

import sbt._
import sbt.complete.{ DefaultParsers, Parser }

import io.gatling.sbt.Utils._

object GatlingTasks {

val lastReport = inputKey[Unit]("Open last report in browser")

val allSimulationIds = taskKey[Set[String]]("List of simulation ids found in reports folder")

val allReports = taskKey[List[Report]]("List of all reports by simulation id and timestamp")

def findAllReports(reportsFolder: File): List[Report] = {
    val allDirectories = (reportsFolder ** DirectoryFilter.&&(new PatternFilter(reportFolderRegex.pattern))).get
    allDirectories.map(file => (file, reportFolderRegex.findFirstMatchIn(file.getPath).get)).map {
        case (file, regexMatch) => Report(file, regexMatch.group(1), regexMatch.group(2))
    }.toList
}

def findAllSimulationIds(allReports: Seq[Report]): Set[String] = allReports.map(_.simulationId).distinct.toSet

def openLastReport(allReports: List[Report], allSimulationIds: Set[String]): Unit = {
    def simulationIdParser(allSimulationIds: Set[String]): Parser[Option[String]] =
        DefaultParsers.ID.examples(allSimulationIds, check = true).?

    def filterReportsIfSimulationIdSelected(allReports: List[Report], simulationId: Option[String]): List[Report] =
        simulationId match {
            case Some(id) => allReports.filter(_.simulationId == id)
            case None => allReports
        }

    Def.inputTaskDyn {
        val selectedSimulationId = simulationIdParser(allSimulationIds).parsed
        val filteredReports = filterReportsIfSimulationIdSelected(allReports, selectedSimulationId)
        val reportsSortedByDate = filteredReports.sorted.map(_.path)
        Def.task(reportsSortedByDate.headOption.foreach(file => openInBrowser((file / "index.html").toURI)))
    }
}
```

}

Of course, `openReport` is called using the results of `allReports` and `allSimulationIds` tasks.
I think I'm close to a functioning input task but I'm still missing something...

Comment: Have you seen http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Extending/Input-Tasks.html and http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Parsing-Input.html?

Comment: Sure, SBT's documentation is always my first stop :) I also dug into `testOnly` and `testQuick` implementation and I discovered that I was basically looking for the `examples` method of the `Parser` trait. However, I didn't manage to get it working but I think I'm onto something. I'll come back and share my solution it it works.

Comment: Ok, I asked because it is easier to help if you have a working parser (or almost working).  If you've tried some things with tab completion, describing that can help as well.  Posting code that doesn't work is a good start- no need to keep trying until it works!

Comment: I added my currently non-functioning code in the OP. I feel it's close to a working solution, but I always end up being bitten by either the compiler (`inputTaskDyn` must return a `Task` or I get `Illegal dynamic reference` errors) or my task simply not working... It looks that it never gets into the body of `inputTaskDyn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Def.inputTaskDyn` returns a value of type `InputTask[T]` and doesn't perform any side effects.  The result needs to be bound to an `InputKey`, like `lastReport`. The return type of `openLastReport` is `Unit`, which means that `openLastReport` will construct a value that will be discarded, effectively doing nothing useful.  Instead, have:

   ```
   def openLastReport(...): InputTask[...] = ...

   lastReport := openLastReport(...).evaluated
   ```

   (Or, the implementation of `openLastReport` can be inlined into the right hand side of `:=`)
2. You probably don't need `inputTaskDyn`, but just `inputTask`.  You only need `inputTaskDyn` if you need to return a task.  Otherwise, use `inputTask` and drop the `Def.task`.